# Como puedo estar monitoriando siempre el valor de una variable para que cuando cambie de valor ejecute un evento?

Tags: c#, eventos

Quiero  que Mi programa siempre este evaluando el valor de una variable  y que cuando cambie de estado ejecute un evento , en este caso la variable es de tipo bool, cuando cambie a True ejecute una accion y se reinicie para que vuelva a esperar a que cambie de valor Nuevamente

Comment: No conozco mucho C#, pero lo que necesitas es algún tipo de observable. Trabajando de manera imperativa (`if (this.foo) bar()`) no podrás hacer lo que quieres, necesitas trabajar de manera reactiva, con observables o flujos que te permitan efectuar acciones cuando llegan nuevos datos. En programación reactiva en vez de tener un booleano tienes un observable de booleano, que te permite ejecutar código cuando llega un nuevo valor (si filtras el observable, solo llegarán valores cuando haya cambios por ejemplo). De todas maneras, tu pregunta está basada en opiniones, te recomiendo investigar :)

Comment: Has realizado 3 preguntas que entiendo apuntan a los mismo. Y en ninguna de ellas, has puesto todos los detalles que involucran tu problema, por ejemplo aquí no señalas que el dato viene desde un PLC (o ya no es así?). Entonces difícilmente vas a encontrar la solución que buscas.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el concepto de "eventos" y "delegados". Los eventos permiten notificar a otras partes del programa cuando ocurre un cambio en el estado de una variable.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo implementarlo:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    // Declaración del delegado para el evento
    public delegate void VariableChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

    // Declaración del evento
    public static event VariableChangedEventHandler VariableChanged;

    // Variable a observar
    private static bool _myVariable;

    public static bool MyVariable
    {
        get { return _myVariable; }
        set
        {
            if (_myVariable != value)
            {
                _myVariable = value;
                // Si la variable cambió, disparar el evento
                OnVariableChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }

    // Método para disparar el evento
    protected static void OnVariableChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        VariableChanged?.Invoke(null, e);
    }

    // Método que manejará el evento
    private static void HandleVariableChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("La variable cambió a true. Acción ejecutada.");
        // Aquí colocarías la lógica que deseas ejecutar cuando la variable cambie a true.
        // Puedes poner la lógica aquí mismo o llamar a otro método.
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        // Suscribir el método HandleVariableChanged al evento VariableChanged
        VariableChanged += HandleVariableChanged;

        // Simulamos cambios en la variable para probar el evento
        MyVariable = false;
        MyVariable = true;
        MyVariable = false;
        MyVariable = true;
    }
}
```

Este ejemplo tiene una variable **_myVariable** de tipo **bool**. He  definido un evento **VariableChanged** que se dispara cuando **_myVariable** cambia a **true**. Además, hemos creado un delegado **VariableChangedEventHandler** que representa el tipo de método que manejará el evento.

El método **OnVariableChanged** se encarga de disparar el evento cuando **_myVariable** cambia a **true**. El método **HandleVariableChanged** es el método que se ejecutará cuando el evento se dispare, y es donde colocarás la lógica que deseas que se ejecute cuando la variable cambie a **true**.

Finalmente, en el método **Main**, hemos suscrito el método **HandleVariableChanged** al evento **VariableChanged** y hemos simulado cambios en la variable **MyVariable** para probar el evento.